# Which Messages are supported for subscriptions in commercetools

Tags: message, subscriptions, commercetools

I'm currently playing with and validating commercetools api.
I want to subscribe to a certain SQS queue, in order to push messages to this queue. 
However if im trying to add a subscription for a certain message type, the api returns:

> {"statusCode":400,"message":"The TypeId 'DeliveryAdded' is unknown or not supported by subscriptions.","errors":[{"code":"InvalidInput","message":"The TypeId 'DeliveryAdded' is unknown or not supported by subscriptions."}]}] with root cause

For resourceTypeId, I use the above mentioned names (e.g. DeliveryAdded)
The request itself is fine.
I tried some different types, always with the same result. Is there any MessageType, which is actually supported for subscriptions ?

Edit:

> POST https://api.sphere.io/some-project/subscriptions HTTP/1.1

```
{
"destination" : {
  "type" : "SQS",
  "accessKey" : "XXXXXXXX",
  "accessSecret" : "XXXXXXXX",
  "region" : "EU",
  "queueUrl" : "https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXX/YYYYYYYY"
},
"messages" : [ {
  "resourceTypeId" : "CustomerCreated"
} ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the `CustomerCreated` Message the `resourceTypeId` should be `customer`

please find a list of supported resource type ids on:
http://dev.commercetools.com/http-api-projects-subscriptions.html#changesubscription

Comment: Thanks, It turned out, that I mixed up resourceTypeId with types. But still its not working. Now getting `{"statusCode":500,"message":"Oops. This shouldn't happen.","errors":[{"code":"General","message":"Oops. This shouldn't happen."}]}]`. I didnt changed request url or anything, except what you mentioned. The given error message is not helping :/

Comment: The problem is with a region you have specified in the subscription. Region `EU` does not exist, you need to use one of these: `eu-west-1`, `eu-central-1` for AWS European region

Comment: Yes, That did the trick. Thank you so much, guys. I think an approvement to the api would be great, if a certain region (or other fields) are not correctly supplied.

Comment: @lunatikz sure thing. It definitely should be a 400 error with clear explanation that AWS region "EU" does not exist (and maybe a hint about supported regions)

Comment: @tenshi I'm not usre about this - AWS creates new regions like crazy and hardcoding the existing regions would just lead to commercetools needing to play catch up with AWS.  A better error text would help more (e.g. foobar.eu-west-1.xxxx/foo/bar  does not seem to be an SQS queue)

Answer (score 1):

you can subscribe to the messages that are documented in the persistent Message API: http://dev.commercetools.com/http-api-projects-messages.html

So "DeliveryAdded" is a message. It could be that you have put the Message type as resourceTypeId (which is "order" in the case of the "DeliveryAdded" message since it's a message related to a change on the order resource).

Can you post your request JSON?

PS: you don't have to have the persistent Messages activated to subscribe to messages.

Comment: I updated my question, additinal i tried using the CustomerCreated Message. When I create a user on sphere, I can see the message, if I poll it from the api. But subscription is still not working